# Janela para selecionar imagem de um local no servidor

Tags: javascript

Meu problema é o seguinte: eu tenho uma página onde devo selecionar uma imagem para ser exibida na tela. Essas imagens estão em um diretório específico que vai ficar no servidor. Atualmente, estou chamando as imagens de forma aleatória e exibindo na tela, porém, eu quero chamar essas imagens de uma forma que seja aberta uma janela exibindo as imagens daquele diretório para que eu possa escolher a imagem e carregar na tela. O código da página o do js são esses:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <h1 class="page-header">
        <table width="400px" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="image" name="selectImage" src="../layout/imagens/Abrir.png" onClick="image()">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h1>
    <div id="image"></div>
```

O js:

```
function image() {
global_points = new Array();
global_effects = new Array();

random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 1) + 1);
img = new Image();
img.src = "../radiografias/" + random + ".jpg";
document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "<img style=\" 
cursor:crosshair\" id='logo' href=\"#\" onmousedown= \"coordenadas(event)\" 
src=\"" +
    img.src + "\" width= 1050 />";
reset();
}
```

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, agradeço muito.

Comment: As imagens possuem nome em sequência? Qual seria?

Comment: Os nomes das imagens são numéricos, no meu caso, vão de 1 a 17...

Comment: Vc usa PHP?....

Comment: Uso tbm.........

Comment: Blz... estou postando a resposta agora mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisará criar uma função que irá abrir a janela que exibirá as imagens. Ao clicar numa imagem, o `src` dela será enviada para a função `image()`.

**1º. Crie a função**

```
function abreJanela(){
   window.open("janela.php", "_blank", "width=600, height=400");
}
```

Você pode ajustar as propriedades da janela como achar melhor (`"width=600, height=400"`).

**2º. Altere o `onClick` do `input` para a função de abrir a janela:**

```
onClick="abreJanela()"
```

**3º. Altere a função `image()` para receber como parâmetro a imagem clicada na janela e atribuir ao `img.src`:**

A função deve ficar desta forma:

```
function image(imagem) {
   global_points = new Array();
   global_effects = new Array();

   img = new Image();
   img.src = imagem;
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "<img style=\" cursor:crosshair\" id='logo' href=\"#\" onmousedown= \"coordenadas(event)\" src=\"" +       img.src + "\" width= 1050 />";
   reset();
}
```

### Janela

Crie um arquivo `.php` (no exemplo eu nomeei `janela.php`, mas você usa o nome que quiser).

O arquivo da janela deverá ter apenas o conteúdo abaixo. Os estilos das imagens (tamanho, cor da borda etc. vc pode ajustar como achar melhor):

```
<style>
img{
   height: 100px;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   cursor: pointer;
}

img:hover{
   border-color: #36F86A;
}
</style>


<?php
// loop para exibir as 17 imagens
for($x=1; $x<=17; $x++){
?>

<img src="../radiografias/<?php echo $x ?>.jpg">

<?php
}
?>

<script>
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for(var x=0; x<imgs.length; x++){
   imgs[x].addEventListener("click", function(){

      window.opener.image(this.src); // envia para a função a imagem escolhida
      window.close(); // fecha a janela ao escolher uma imagem

   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou e não funcionou ao mesmo tempo kkkk. Tipo as imagens ficaram todas transparentes e a mesma coisa aconteceu quando elas foram carregadas na tela. Vc pode observar aqui: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sytsezjk0VotNs1cjI1CWzY-y9-shbdH

Comment: Ah sim, tem que ver o caminho das imagens em `<img src="../radiografias/<?php echo $x ?>.jpg">`

Comment: Era isso mesmo...muito obrigado. Funcionou bem agora, mas, só no Mozilla kkkk

Comment: Serio?! Eu testei no Chrome e funcionou. Qual o problema que acontece no Chrome?

Comment: no Chrome diz que abreJanela is not defined

Comment: Descobri o erro. Foi algo muito simples. Era só eu retirar o número da porta na minha url, pq estou executando com o PhpStorm. Agora funcionou

Comment: Vlw amigão, vc é o cara

Comment: Dá uns pontinhos a mais, se gostou bastante da resposta rs

Comment: Ok...pode deixar, vlw

Comment: Amanhã vou tentar resolver aquela sua outra resposta das legendas... me parece meio complexa e hj estou meio sem tempo pra ver. Mas se alguém conseguir resolver, ótimo.